# Помогите правильно сделать переход на другой роут при клике

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Пишу канбан-доску на реакте и нужно сделать так чтобы при клике по названию задачи происходил переход на другой роут и там отрисовывал описание конкретной задачи по которой был совершен клик.
На данный момент выводил только Not found, не понимаю как правильно сделать этот переход и как в компоненте DetailPage получить инфу о конкретной задаче.
Использую: react-router-dom: 6.21.2

App.tsx
[image]

Cards.tsx тут по клику должен быть переход на другой роут
[image]

DetailPage.tsx
[image]

Comment: Уберите скрины и добавьте в вопрос код текстом